# Second array not printing

Tags: java, arrays, binary

When I run my code in my compiler, the second array is not printing for some reason even though it is essentially the same code for creating the first array copy and pasted. The first array does print.

Can someone tell me why the second array is not printing?

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    int x;
    int d = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a base ten number between 0 and 255, inclusive.");
    n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a base ten number between 0 and 255, inclusive.");
    x = s.nextInt();
    int[] bin = new int[8];
     int[] bin2 = new int[8];
    while (count < 8) {
        bin[i] = n % 2;
        i++;
        n = n / 2;
        count++;
    }

   System.out.print("First binary number: ");
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {


      System.out.print(bin[j] + " ");
    }


    while (count2 < 8) {
        bin2[d] = x % 2;
        d++;
        x = x / 2;
        count2++;
    }

   System.out.print("\n\nSecond binary number: ");
    for (int z = x - 1; z >= 0; z--) {


      System.out.print(bin2[z] + " ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop from

```
for (int z = x - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
```

To

```
for (int z = d - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
```

As in your earlier loop, x might have become 0 and you are trying to do like:

```
z = -1 and z >=0
```

in your for loop, which is why it doesn't enter the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, you are counting down from `i` to zero. In the second loop, the equivalent of `i` is `d`.

But instead of counting down from `d`, you are counting down from `x`, which gives you the incorrect result. So change that do:

```
for (int z = d - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
  System.out.print(bin2[z] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
System.out.print("\n\nSecond binary number: ");
for (int z = x - 1; z >= 0; z--) {


  System.out.print(bin2[z] + " ");
}
```

To

```
System.out.print("\n\nSecond binary number: ");
for (int z = d - 1; z >= 0; z--) {


  System.out.print(bin2[z] + " ");
}
```